# Is it better to use Reflect.defineProperty instead of Object.defineProperty?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

Using eslint with React configurations I get an **error** when using `Object.defineProperty`. The error says:

> Avoid using `Object.defineProperty`, instead use `Reflect.defineProperty`. (prefer-reflect)

On the eslint [documentation of prefer-reflect](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-reflect) they say it's deprecated, the reason being:

> The original intent of this rule now seems misguided as we have come to understand that `Reflect` methods are not actually intended to replace the `Object` counterparts the rule suggests, but rather exist as low-level primitives to be used with proxies in order to replicate the default behavior of various previously existing functionality.

Then my question is: is there any advantage in using `Reflect.defineProperty` instead of `Object.defineProperty`?

Comment: Yes, the deprecation notice explains it just fine. You should not use this rule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a slight difference between [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and [`Reflect.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/defineProperty): the former returns the target object and throws an exception when the descriptor could not be applied (e.g. when the property is non-writable or non-configurable or when the object is non-extensible), while the latter does return a boolean value whether it worked.

I'd argue that this makes `Object.defineProperty` a bit more useful, unless you're implementing a [`defineProperty` proxy trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/defineProperty).

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement the last answer, with `Object.defineProperty` you must use a `try/catch` block for contolling exceptions while with `Reflect.defineProperty` you just can do a boolean check with an `if` statement for correct property creation.